# Is it possible to define a macro variable through make?

Tags: compiling, c, makefile

Below is my c code:

```
#include

main() {    
    #ifdef HELLO
        printf(" hello ");
    #else
        printf(" else ");
    #endif
}
```

And my Makefiles is:

```
all:
        gcc uss_main.c -o out
```

Here I am trying to print `hello` by executing the binary `out`. I want to define the macro `HELLO` only at the time of doing make. I have tried using `make HELLO=11`but it only printing the else part, I am pretty new to make. Please help me to enhance my Makefile. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This [entry from stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9052792/how-to-pass-macro-definition-from-make-command-line-arguments-d-to-c-source) might answer it.

Comment: [this might be helpful for your query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35072514/10477257)

Answer (score 1):

You can define macro by using GCC compiler flag like this:

```
gcc -DHELLO=1 uss_main.c -o out
```

If you want to pass it to make, you need to modify Makefile. Something like this:

```
USE_HELLO = $(if $(HELLO),-DHELLO=$(HELLO),)

all:
     gcc $(USE_HELLO) uss_main.c -o out
```